# How can we create carousel image slider using Javascript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am newbie web development please help me to learn in the proper way!

We will not use any framework or libraries.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far and why it isn't working. Hint: have a look at css transformations and such...

Comment: Pleas help to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple exemple

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('#slider>div');
var margin = 0;

setInterval(function(){
  margin = (margin + 400) % 1200
  slider.style['margin-left'] = '-'+margin +'px' 
},5 * 1000);
```

```css
 #slider{
    width : 400px;
    height : 160px;
    overflow : hidden;
}

#slider div{      
   height : 160px;
   transition : all 1s
}

#slider>div{
   width : 1200px;
   height : 160px;
   transition : all 1s
}

#slider>div>div{  
      width : 400px;
      float : left;
}

#red{
   background-color : red
}

#blue{
   background-color : blue
}

#green{
   background-color : green
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
   <div>
      <div class="slide" id=red></div>  
      <div class="slide" id=blue></div>  
      <div class="slide" id=green></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want it using Mouse Event. Like I drag it from right to left(vice versa). Drag will Happen. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: like Javascript carousel drag event. In the image array it will slide to another image.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to navigate through an array that contains the urls of the pictures one by one, and everytime you change the src of the img tag that you're using by assigning the picture url of the actual index..

```
document.getElementById('image').src=pictures[i];
```

Where pictures is your array.

Here's a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/nfzo191a/1/) , And you can add the CSS that you want (transitions...etc).